# Reading data from another file in a project

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, file-io

I  got stuck in an issue that I am sure is easy to overcome. The main class is used to build a gui:

// AlladinLamp.java

```
package alladinlamp;


import javax.swing.table.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;

class AlladinLamp  {

int fnh;
ComboBox runners;

[ ...code ]

AlladinLamp()  {

[ ...code ]

runners = new JComboBox( numberOfRunners );
       runners.setMaximumRowCount(5); 
       runners.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {   
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
             String  runnersNumber = ( String )runners.getSelectedItem();
             fnh = Integer.parseInt( runnersNumber ); 
}

[ ...code ]

public int getFNH() { return fnh; }

[ ...code ]

SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()  {
            @Override
            public void run()  {
                AlladinLamp lamp = new AlladinLamp();                 
            }
        });

}
```

I want to be able to read fnh from another file

```
package alladinlamp; 

Class Processes  {

   int fullNH;
   AlladinLamp lamp;



   Processes()  {
      lamp = new AlladinLamp();
      fullNH = lamp.getFNH();

[ ...code ]

}

[ ...code ]

}
```

But it´s not happening ( fnh = null ). The integer is read in the same file it was created though. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what is happening here is that the actionPerformed() method in AlladinLamp, which sets the variable youre interested in, is being called **after** the constructor for your Processes class...which is trying to use that number.   Easy thing to try here is to insert a System.out.println in that actionPerformed and at the end of your AlladinLamp and Processes constructors and see the order in which things are happening.

It has nothing to do with packages as the other poster mentions.  The default visibility if you dont specify public is package level visibility so that should be fine as is.

forgot to mention....remember that the Swing library is an event-based GUI library.  So your GUI is going to be constructed first.  That actionPerformed method won't be called until later...once your whole UI is set up and you've chosen something from the combobox.

Comment: Hi, I placed those statements where you asked me to. I got no output when I placed it in the constructior of the Process class. It is as though it´s not linked at all to th main class.

Comment: Not understanding this.  Are you actually using the Process class anywhere?  Maybe posting more code would be helpful.